# Cannot run the code and print out the result, using xpath and webdriver to click the pulldown menu

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

Cannot run the code and print out the result, using xpath and webdriver to click the pulldown menu by following codes

```
 from selenium import webdriver
 from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
 from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
 from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

 driver = webdriver.Firefox()
 driver.get('URL')
 driver.maximize_window()
 wait = WebDriverWait(driver,40)
 wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'div.combobox-input-wrap a[data-value="rbAll"]'))).click()
 wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//div[@class="droplist-item"]/a[contains(.,"Headline Category")]'))).click()
 wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//div[@id="rbAfter2006"]//div[@class="combobox-input-wrap"]/a[contains(.,"ALL")]'))).click()
 wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//div[@class="droplist-group"]//ul[@class="droplist-items"]//li/a[contains(.,"Announcements and Notices")]'))).click()
 ele=wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//div[@class="droplist-group droplist-submenu level2"]//ul//li/a[contains(.,"New Listings (Listed Issuers/New Applicants)")]')))
 ele.location_once_scrolled_into_view
 ele.click()
 ele2=wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//div[@class="droplist-group droplist-submenu level3"]//ul//li/a[contains(.,"Allotment Results")]')))
 ele2.location_once_scrolled_into_view
 ele2.click()

 html = driver.page_source
 print html
```

the Error Log show as below when run it.

```
File "run.py", line 6, in <module>
   driver = webdriver.Firefox()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 167, in __init__
keep_alive=True)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 156, in __init__
self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 251, in start_session
response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 320, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be printing the value inside brackets, i.e.

```
html = driver.page_source
print(html)
```